# how to convert localized Date String to NSDate

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, date-conversion, localized

I have NSString *localized_Date = minutesSinceMidnightToLocalizedTime (time units)

I get this string as 4:30 am, 10.00pm

how do I convert this string to NSDate?
PLease let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's a bit long code, but I wanted to make it as readable as possible.
This code uses minutesSinceMidnight instead of the localized string.

```
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *currentDateComponents = [calendar components:NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit fromDate:currentDate];
NSDateComponents *currentDateToMidnight = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[currentDateToMidnight setHour:-[currentDateComponents hour]];
[currentDateToMidnight setMinute:-[currentDateComponents minute]];
[currentDateToMidnight setSecond:-[currentDateComponents second]];
NSDate *midnight = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:currentDateToMidnight toDate:currentDate options:0];
NSDateComponents *midnightToDesiredDate = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[midnightToDesiredDate setMinute:minutesSinceMidnight];
NSDate *desiredDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:midnightToDesiredDate toDate:midnight options:0];
```

Comment: hi rbkujawa, if I have minutesSinceMidnight as 120, I am getting 09:00:00 +0000 time which is 7 hrs ahead of the current time.

Comment: What timezone is set on your device/simulator? Do you need date with minutesSinceMidnight in some specific time zone or just the current device's time zone?

Comment: I have pacific daylight time.

Comment: Do you need date with minutesSinceMidnight in some specific time zone or just the current device's time zone?

Comment: I need date with just current device's time zone

Comment: So it works fine - 2 AM(120 minutes after midnight) PDT is 9:00 GMT(+0000)

Comment: is there any way to get the time as it is? with no GMT conversion?

Comment: It's just about date presentation, the NSDate objects you create are ok. In order to present a NSDate with your current location you need to use NSDateFormatter, specify its date format and timezone. It's very easy. Here is a link to the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html

Comment: I need to compare date objects in local time zone. how do I do that with GMT time? can you please let me know

Comment: It's a separate question but I will answer you here: you can either use NSCalendar's components:fromDate:toDate:options: method if you need concrete difference, or use NSDate's compare: method

Answer (score 0):

NSDateFormatter is your friend, use the formats that suits your date/time

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease]; 
[df setDateFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"dd MMM yyyy HH:mm"]]; 
NSDate *_date = [df dateFromString:string];
```

Johan

Comment: How do I get NSDate from minutesSinceMidnight (which is NSInteger)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
NSString *dateString = @"4:30 am";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];

NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: that does not give me a proper date.

Comment: Yes, that will give proper time. If you want to change the date format `[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss VVVV"];`. This format will give proper date with time.

Comment: NSString *dateString = @"10:59 pm";
        NSLog(@"datestring %@", dateString);
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        
       // [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss VVVV"];
        NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
        
        NSLog(@"converted date %@", date);    `code` I get date as null object. any idea?

Comment: You have only the time i.e., 10:59 pm, so with that input, how can you get proper date. You should have proper string as `@"2013/05/11 12:34 pm"`, then only you convert string to NSDate.